# How to track users login/logout timing on SimpleSAMLPhp IDP?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

We want to track user's login/logout time in database at SimpleSAMLPhp which we are using it as IDP in our SSO login process. 
I've been told to insert new log record in MySql database as soon as user is authenticated on IDP and update the same entry once he logs out and I have to make changes in simplesamlphp files.

I found out SimpleSAMLPhp have [Statistics module](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/statistics:statistics) where it reads data from specified log file and display the statistics. But I don't want to interact with log files.

What could be better solution reading the log files or Adding code changes in SimpleSAMLPhp files to insert log records where Login/Logout events are written, Can someone please give me suggestions?

Comment: My guesses: IDP = Identity provider, SSO = Single sign-on. Which makes the sentence: "we are using it as identity provider in our single sign-on login process."

Comment: Yeah isn't that obvious :P

Comment: If things are so obvious to you, then why the problems with creating a simple database for logging? PS and FYI: I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: Chill man no need be sarcastic....I've already put the single-sign-on, simplesamlphp tags on the question. Also IDP and SSO are acronyms, People who are familiar with SimpleSAMLPhp should not have any confusion understanding them. It's alright downvotes don't bother me.

Comment: I am chilled... :-0 So, do you have access to the user's login/logout time in PHP? I assume you do. You probably want to create a MySQL database. Right? Or perhaps a SQLite file? Have you made a choice? And if you did, why can't you proceed?

Comment: I have full access on simeplesamlphp setup, It will be MySql database..I'm not sure exactly where to write the code and how to organize it in a proper way, I've updated the question as well.

Comment: That's a good update. I can only tell you that it is a bad idea to _modify_ a library you don't own, if that's what you're suggesting, for the obvious reasons: With every update you need to repeat this, and your codes might become incompatible. So either you must let SimpleSAMLPhp make a call to your code to do the logging (preferred way), or you can read the log files. As you might have guessed, I don't know anything about SimpleSAMLPhp, so it is not up to me to advice you about this.

Comment: It's alright ..Thanks for your suggestions